# Problem creating onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to add an onItemClickListener to my ListView

```
streamListView.setAdapter(this.streamAdapter);
            this.streamListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageDetailActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

but I get the error:

```
The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<MessageDetailActivity>) is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the annonymos class is of type `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` use `YOURACTIVITYNAME.this` to refer to the activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
....
streamListView.setAdapter(this.streamAdapter);
     this.streamListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
>>>>>       Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MessageDetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
     });
...
}
```